# Creating New Firebase Project: "There was an unknown error while creating the project"

Tags: firebase, firebase-console

I can't create a new project. I tried 5 times, each time my previous project name had been taken but not created.

Error message: "There was an unknown error while creating the project"

[image: Firebase Error]

Comment: I had a similar problem today. After trying various solutions, It only worked after I went Incognito. It's probably a browser issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems there was a bug, as I'm seeing the projects have been created now.

Comment: There was indeed an outage. See this page for the latest status: https://status.firebase.google.com/incident/Console/18009

Comment: I am still facing this issue. Tried five times just wanted to create sample project.